# Nvidia Quadro M1000M on Dell Precision 5510 - 14.04 LTS black screen

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I'm trying to get things work on my PC, a Dell Precision 5510 with dual graphics, Intel and Nvidia, but I cannot use properly the NVIDIA M1000M graphics card.
I've tried (almost) all the soutions mentioned all around in internet, but none had worked.
Here are some terminal outputs :

```
lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

gives:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:191d] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:06e5]
Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] [10de:13b1] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:06e5]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Then:
`Additional Drivers` tab gives me proprietary drivers used :
`361.45-18`

Every time I try to install a new driver version, a black screen with a fault message appears. Then I switch to console and use Nvidia Tool `prime-select intel` to select intel card again. Then restart `lightdm` and all seems ok again - using Intel Graphics, indeed.
i've also tried solutions with `nouveau.modeset=0` into GRUB, but no success.

`uname -r` gives `4.4.0-45-generic`

Anyone can help? May need some more info?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nvidia recommends 367.57 only for that card. The driver you installed does not support your card.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I'll try right now the version you mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Same behaviour: selected the driver -> reboot -> black screen -> switch back with `sudo prime-select intel` -> reboot -> ok with intel graphics.